# Host Name Site Collection: Connection close

Tags: host-named

I created a Host Name Site Collection on an existing Web Application that already had a root site, using the following PowerShell Script:

```
$webappName = "http://xxxx/"
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication http://xxxx/
$user = "xxxx"

New-SPSite xxxx -HostHeaderWebApplication $webappName -Name 'xxxx' -OwnerAlias $user -language 1033 -Template 'STS#0'S
```

After that, I updated the hosts file with the following entry:

> 172.16.xxx.xx     Site

Last but not least, I changed the bindings to the IIS Web Site:

[image]

Now, when I try to access the site, it says:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015
>   11:42:12 GMT Connection: close

Answer (score 1):

In IIS bindings, you should only have the blank binding you have on first row as SharePoint takes care of this with HNSCs. So remove second binding.

Comment: Thank you Jussi. I removed the binding, and also had to Disable Loopback through the Registry Editor. I am now able to access the site collection from inside the server, but when I try from outside, I am getting `502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.` Any thoughts? No alternate access mapping is necessary when using HNSCs, right?